# Facebook+php: upload photo to your friends' specific album

Tags: php, facebook, upload, photos

I would like my application to upload photo to a specific album of my friend.
photos.upload(); can take albumid and userid as parameters, but it says "invalid albumId" whenever I try to upload it into my friends' albums, where as it successfully gives out the pictureId if it were to upload in my own Albums.

Comment: That's not actually possible in the web UI is it?

Comment: I know Facebook is playing fast and loose with privacy settings, but can you really add photos to another user's album?  Seems like this is ripe for abuse?

Comment: It occurs to me: if you're trying to build a shared album the you could instead create a private group and you should (hopefully) be able to upload photos to one of the group's albums with the API. However if you're trying to modify someone else's album without their permission I expect you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. There is no permission combination that will allow this. You can only share photos on the wall/timeline of the friend.